# How to initialize jQuery plugin loaded using $.getScript

Tags: jquery, plugins, magnific-popup, getscript

I am checking if a jQuery plugin ([magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)) script is already loaded into the DOM, if it isn't then I want to load it:

```
    if(typeof $.fn.magnificPopup !== 'undefined'){
        console.log('Plugin exists');
    }else{
        $.getScript('vendor/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', function(){
            console.log('Script loaded.');
        });         
    }
```

Now normally I would initialize magnific popup like this:

```
    $('.gallery-img').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });
```

But this isn't working. How do I initialize the plugin and apply it to elements on my page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to integrate the ideas:

```
function loadPopup(popupParams) {
    if ( typeof $.fn.magnificPopup !== 'undefined' ) {
        console.log('Plugin exists');
        $('#foo').magnificPopup(popupParams);
    }
    else {
        // Watch out! Relative URLs not recommended. Start with a '/' and traverse.
        $.getScript('vendor/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', function() {
            console.log('Script loaded.');
            $('#foo').magnificPopup(popupParams);
        });         
    }
}
```

And at some point after that's been defined:

```
loadPopup({type: 'image', gallery: { enabled: true } });
```

Variations are of course possible, such as parameterizing the element that gets inserted into.

If $('#foo') doesn't exist yet, then of course it won't work. jQuery is happy to do nothing if the selector result set is empty. Use debugging to determine if it's empty or not. If necessary, move the `loadPopup` to *after* the image has loaded, likely in the `ajax` `success` callback.

Comment: I had already tried this, still not working - I am adding the popup to images loaded via ajax after the script is loaded. Could this be why it is not working? Is there a way to use `.on()` on a jQuery plugin?

Comment: Edited to reflect your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(typeof $.fn.magnificPopup !== 'undefined'){
    console.log('Plugin exists');
}else{
    $.getScript('vendor/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', function(){
        console.log('Script loaded.');


        $('.gallery-img').magnificPopup({
          type: 'image',
         gallery: {
            enabled: true
          }

         });
    });         
}
```

This should work because `$.getScript` is an asynchronous call, and it's within its `complete` callback you can expect the fetched script to have been successfully loaded.

The way you had it originally, the `$('.gallery-img').magnificPopup({ });` portion of your code was probably running *before* the plugin script was fully fetched.

NB: A "bad" alternative to get your original code to run could have been:

```
SetTimeout(function(){
   $('.gallery-img').magnificPopup({ });
}, 2000);
```

The "2000" is an arbitrary 2 seconds you're giving (hoping the ajax call before it would have completed). Now, we know you have no guarantee it will indeed have completed. Therefore, stick with the first option.

**EDIT**

I suspect that my initial code suggestion will not work when the plugin had indeed already been loaded. So I'm revising:

```
if(typeof $.fn.magnificPopup !== 'undefined'){
    console.log('Plugin exists');
    doPopup('.gallery-img');
}else{
    $.getScript('vendor/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', function(){
        console.log('Script loaded.');

        doPopup('.gallery-img');

    });         
}


function doPupup(selector){
        $(selector).magnificPopup({
          type: 'image',
         gallery: {
            enabled: true
          }

         });
}
```